# What is the php @ sign for

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the use of @ symbol in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php)

Hello all, an easy one for you,

what does the @ sign mean when placed before a php function call?

Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

it means it won't print out any error in that function, if one occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Suppress error reporting

Answer (score 2):

**[PHP's error suppress operator](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2006/05/07/php-the-operator/)** used to suppress error messages.

**SideNote:** Avoid it as much as you can, also it slows down performance heavily :)

Comment: +1 for the sidenote, that's news for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's PHP's error control operator. In short, errors generated by an expression prepended with the symbol will be ignored.

From the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php