# What is the meaning of @ in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the use of @ symbol in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php)

I like to know the purpose and meaning of @ in php codes.
For instance, @umask or @ini_set. What's the difference without @ and with @?

Answer (score 5):

**[PHP's error suppress operator](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2006/05/07/php-the-operator/)** used to suppress error messages.

**SideNote:** Avoid it as much as you can, also it slows down performance heavily and not allowed to be used in `ini_get` and `ini_set` functions in future php versions.

Answer (score 1):

"Swallow an error", continue despite an error occuring. An non-critical operation augmented with @ will not abort script execution.

Answer (score 1):

@ symbol is an error control operator  check out manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)