# Why use @ before variable in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the use of the @ symbol in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php)
>   [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

what does using  `<?php echo @$fnameerror; ?>` mean. why use @ before variable in php

Comment: See [What is the use of @ symbol in php?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php).

Comment: @Matthew I get the feeling shaz knows what it does in general, just not why it would be used to prefix a variable.

Answer (score 26):

[error control operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) .. suppresses error messages  ..

Answer (score 9):

@ is pure evil.  It's not a good idea to use.  You can find an explanation about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

It can cause massive debugging headaches because it will even suppress critical errors.

Comment: Actually wrong. If you define a custom error handler, you can still receive all messages despite the @ suppression operator. Therefore it's in fact preferable to e.g. isset() decoration.

Comment: Maybe so, but I've seen way more people use it without a custom error handler and have way too many headaches dealing with it.

Answer (score 8):

It's used to avoid the error notice.

Answer (score 6):

The only reason I can think of to use the error suppression operator before a variable would be to suppress `E_NOTICE` errors if the variable is undefined.

As others have mentioned, this is a bad idea. It's much better to actually deal with errors than ignore them.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid notices and warnings use @ sign before variable