# html to pdf conversion using tcpdf

Tags: php

```
$html=$this->load->view('r2013ms/Long_term_agreement',$data);
$obj_pdf->writeHTML($html);
$obj_pdf->Output('Agree.pdf', 'I');
```

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: tcpdf/tcpdf.php

Line Number: 17155

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: tcpdf/tcpdf.php

Line Number: 17522

TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Answer (score 1):

When you have "TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file" it's because you have displayed something in screen. Maybe another warning.

Try to put an "@" before the function's call, that will supress the error message
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151418/why-use-before-variable-can-someone-pls-explain)

if all works fine, you know where search the error