# What is the meaning in '@' is used in php echo?

Tags: php, codeigniter

php echo starts with '@' sign for show a variable,

Example:

```
<?php echo @$user_profile['id'];?>
```

why @ sign used here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why use @before variable. can someone pls explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151418/why-use-before-variable-can-someone-pls-explain)

Comment: so it means hide the error

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php

Comment: @kumar Not an error, a notice, which may/may not be an error. If the DOM or where ever this is executed is not looking for the output of `$user_profile['id']` it will be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of the @ symbol in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php)

Comment: ok thank you for update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

That is just suppressing notices when the variable is not available.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php for more info.

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When used with an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

[More info here](http://code2care.org/tutorials/php/PHP-Error-Control-Operators-Tutorial.php)