# difference between define(...) and @define(...)

Tags: php

Quick question, what is the difference between the following two declarations:

```
define('I_LIKE_AT_SIGNS', false);
```

and

```
@define('I_LIKE_AT_SIGNS', true);
```

I.e. what does the `@`-sign do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of @ symbol in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php)

Comment: 6 upvotes for a RTFM type of question? A quick google search for "php at sign" would have answered your question.

Comment: @NikiC: I agree, had a brain freeze and defaulted to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`@` symbol](http://php.net/@) is PHP's only error control operator, and when prepended to any expression, all errors associated with that expression are suppressed.

In this case, any errors associated with your `define` expression will be suppressed.

Use of the `@` error suppression technique generally isn't encouraged or recommended. Instead, it's much better to use other error capture techniques so you can detect and handle the error.

Comment: It's also called "shut up" operator.

Comment: @Gedrox, This is Funny!

Answer (score 8):

It prevents error messages I believe.

"*In PHP, it is used just before an expression to make the interpreter suppress errors that would be generated from that expression" -- From wikipedia*

Use with Caution!!

Comment: And it is slow and makes your program hard to debug

Comment: Agreed, it has caused me big problems in the past! i'll update my answer ;)