# Notice: Undefined property - how do I avoid that message in PHP?

Tags: properties, null, php-5.3

Hello I am making this call:

```
$parts = $structure->parts;
```

Now $structure only has *parts* under special circumstances, so the call returns me null. Thats fine with me, I have a *if($parts) {...}* later in my code. Unfortunately after the code finished running, I get this message:

**Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$parts in ...**

How can I suppress this message?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The function `isset` should do exactly what you need.

[PHP: isset - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Example:

```
$parts = (isset($structure->parts) ? $structure->parts : false);
```

Answer (score 16):

Landed here in 2020 and surprised that noone has mentioned:

1.[As of PHP 7.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
$parts = $structure->parts ?? false;
```

2.A [frowned-upon practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36892995/6201440) - [the stfu operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

```
$parts = @$structure->parts;
```

Answer (score 6):

maybe this

```
$parts = isset($structure->parts) ? $structure->parts : false ;
```

Answer (score 6):

With the help of **property_exists()** you can easily remove "Undefined property" notice from your php file.

Following is the example:

```
if (property_exists($structure,'parts')) {
    $parts = $structure->parts;
}
```

To know more http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

Comment: Careful with this! This will not cover the case of "magically" accessible properties (via [`__get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)), whereas both `isset` and the null coalescing operator `??` will.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a helper function for multilevel chaining. Let's say you want to do something like `$obj1->obj2->obj3->obj4`, my helper function returns empty string whenever one of the tiers is not defined or null, so instead of `$obj1->obj2->obj3->obj4` you my use `MyUtils::nested($obj1, 'obj2', 'obj3', 'obj4')`. Also using this helper method will not produce any **notices** or **errors**. Syntactically it is not the best, but practically very comfortable.

```
class MyUtils
{
    // for $obj1->obj2->obj3: MyUtils::nested($obj1, 'obj2', 'obj3')
    // returns '' if some of tiers is null
    public static function nested($obj1, ...$tiers)
    {
        if (!isset($obj1)) return '';
        $a = $obj1;
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tiers); $i++){
            if (isset($a->{$tiers[$i]})) {
                $a = $a->{$tiers[$i]};
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
        return $a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can turn this off in the php.ini file.. you want to turn off E_NOTICE on the error_reporting flag.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE
```

Whether it is wise to do this is another question (to which I suspect the answer is no).

Answer (score -1):

use `@` before access to suppress warnings & errors inline:

```
$v=@$object->field->subfield;
```

**note** This is a bad practice, but it will do the trick