# What is the context of @var in load local infile

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

**PhP**

```
// $numberOption = the number of fields in TableA.
// $csvHeaders   = a single dimention array with all the names of the fields in a CSV file.
// $tableHeaders   = a single dimention array with all the names of the fields in TableA.

for ($a=0; $a < $numberOption; $a++) {
            if ($a == 0) {
                $toVars .= "@var$a";
                $setCols .= $tableHeaders[$a] . " = @var" . $csvHeaders[$a];
            } else {
                $toVars .= ", @var$a";
                $setCols .= ", " . $tableHeaders[$a] . " = @var" . $csvHeaders[$a];
            }
        }

        $sql    = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".addslashes($current_file)."' REPLACE INTO TABLE $current_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '" . '"' . "' ESCAPED BY " . "'\\\\'" . " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES ($toVars) SET $setCols";
```

**The returned value of $sql**

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '\/var\/www\/html\/test_lms\/include\/files\/1349237011-2fb46cd0c360464ebf471755cc9580de-AUTO_INSURANCE.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE auto FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@var0, @var1, @var2, @var3, @var4, @var5, @var6, @var7, @var8, @var9, @var10, @var11, @var12, @var13, @var14, @var15, @var16, @var17, @var18, @var19, @var20, @var21, @var22, @var23, @var24, @var25, @var26, @var27, @var28, @var29) SET callcenter = @var, agent = @varEMPTY, generation_date = @varEMPTY, first_name = @varEMPTY, last_name = @varEMPTY, email = @var3, phone = @var4, address = @var5, city = @var6, state = @var7, dob = @varEMPTY, gender = @varEMPTY, marital_status = @varEMPTY, rented = @varEMPTY, year = @varEMPTY, make = @varEMPTY, model = @varEMPTY, trim = @varEMPTY, vin = @varEMPTY, primary_use = @varEMPTY, miles_oneway = @varEMPTY, mileage = @varEMPTY, license_num = @varEMPTY, license_state = @varEMPTY, education = @varEMPTY, job_title = @varEMPTY, vendors = @var9, license_status = @varEMPTY, zip = @var8, dupe = @varEMPTY
```

Okay clearly in the php line that says `$setCols .= $tableHeaders[$a] . " = @var" . $csvHeaders[$a];` it is initializing `$setCols` with a field name from `tableA` and then the equal sign, then this thing `@var` (which I guess is a mysql variable?), then a csv field name. But the result shows a number attached to the `@var` sign and not a csv field name! Some `@var` have `EMPTY` attached to them and that just means there was no field name from the `$csvHeaders` array to use so `EMPTY` was returned.

Anyway, it works. I am able to load in a csv file just fine and perfectly actually. But I dont understand how it is able to `SET` with `@var#` and not `@varCSVNAME`. Another question is why use `@var` at all? Wouldn't `IGNORE LINES 1 (table field names) SET (csv header names)` work just fine? Why the `@var`'s?

Comment: can you show the contents of `$csvHeaders`, for which the given `sql` is returned.

Comment: `["","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","3","4","5","6","7","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","EMPTY","9","EMPTY","8","EMPTY"]`

Comment: i think it gives the position of a CSV column relative to a table column. So the 6th field in `$tableHeaders` is present in the 3rd column of the CSV.

Comment: yup that is exactly what it does. I knew that little tid bit, but I was under the impression that the way load local infile worked is that you give it table field names in a certain order and then you give those fields values by using `SET` with those values occuring in the same order that their respective field names occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format used in your `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement is

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt'
  REPLACE INTO TABLE t1
  ...
  (@var0, @var1, ...)
  SET column0 = @var0,
  SET column1 = @var1,
  ...
  ;
```

Here `@var0`, `@var1` etc are mysql user variables and `column0`, `column1` etc are mysql table columns. The fields from the csv file would be read into the given mysql user variables `@var0, @var1, ...` in the order of the fields in the csv file.

I don't think there is any syntax which allows you to map the csv header field names to the table columns. So you wouldn't be able to use `IGNORE LINES 1 (table field names) SET (csv header names)`.

Your script uses `$numberOption` to create that many user variables, to which the fields in the csv file will be read into. `$csvHeaders` stores the position of a CSV field relative to the corresponding table column. So `$tableHeaders[6] = 'email';` and `$csvHeaders[6] = 3;` since the `3rd` field of the csv file is the `email` field. In the `LOAD DAT INFILE` statement, the third field from the csv file would be read into the user variable `@var3` and then `SET email = @var3` will set the value of the email column with this variable. Since nothing is being read into `@varEMPTY`, columns set with them will not get any data from the file. Similarly data read into variables like `@var29` which is not used in any `set` will be ignored.

Alternatively you could use `LOAD DATA ... (COL3, COL1, @dummy, COL2, @dummy);`, if the fields in the csv file were `col3, col1, notInTable, col2, notInTable`;. If the columns in the table and fields in the csv file differed in number and order this could be used.

If the columns in the table and fields in the csv file matched in number and order, then `LOAD DATA ... INTO TABLE t1;` would be enough.

If the columns in the table and fields in the csv file matched in number but differed in order, then `LOAD DATA ... INTO TABLE t1 (COL3, COL1, COL2);`.

Answer (score 0):

the `@` symbol is only used for error suppression in PHP. [What is the use of the @ symbol in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php)

`var` is only used when declearing variables inside of a class.

When declaring a variable in PHP you do not have to declare the variable before hand (although it is good practice if you are used to using other languages). You do however have to express that it is a variable by using a prefix of `$`, ex: `$x = 0;`

Using `DATA LOCAL INFILE` through mysql you are able to pass "dummy" parameters to ensure that they are set, even if they don't exist.

Using this line: `$setCols .= $tableHeaders[$a] . " = @var" . $csvHeaders[$a];` seems a little strange to me, as `@var` would be considered a constant of `var` where `@` suppresses the error that the constant doesn't exits.

This then concatenates the rest of the string (in your case `$tableHeaders[$a]."= ".$csvHeaders[$a];`).

Comment: So.. how it is able to SET with @var# and not @varCSVNAME?

Comment: I don't see any instances of "@varCSVNAME" in the code that you supplied.

Comment: `$setCols .= $tableHeaders[$a] . " = @var" . $csvHeaders[$a];` @var is concen to $csvHeaders.