# mysql data to email from php

Tags: php, mysql

Shown data from mysql query in php file:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
  echo 'ID: '.$row['ID']; 
  echo ' First Name: '.$row['First']; 
  echo ' Last Name: '.$row['Last']; 
  echo ' Phone: '.$row['Phone'];
```

}

I need to send those results to email
How to do this? like:

```
$message = 'ID: '.$row['ID'];
```

not working: I receive message "ID:" without result

Comment: Why do you have the `@` symbol before `mail` ?

Comment: Please elaborate on what "not working" means. Are you getting errors?

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie To surpress warnings (a generally bad idea)

Comment: The `@` symbol prevents errors being output check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php).

Comment: Is the mail not getting sent or is the data empty?

Comment: I know, but usually it is used in with variable, but in this case, it was unusall to me, but not working.. he means mail is not sending.. i gues

Comment: I receive message "ID:" without result

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a `$to` address. Moreover, please remove the `@` and don't suppress the errors. 
Also, check if the `$headers` are defined.

Comment: I receive message "ID:" without result

Comment: You need to check your query to see if the row has any data in column `ID`.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [PHPMailer Library](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/). It is used by many php developers, it is very easy to use and is powerful as well.

Comment: What's wrong with using `mail`?  Nothing.  Op needs help determining why his/her attempted use of it is not working.