# "gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file" in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and trying to create thumbs of images. I was successful for some but failed for in some cases. I am getting this following error -

```
<< A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file

Filename: libraries/Image_lib.php

Line Number: 1155 >>
```

i used this code after 'image_lib' library load.

```
ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);
```

any solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i have added my code........ i also have noticed just now that thumbs are creating successfully now, but still i get the warning.

Comment: what version of CI are you using?

Comment: ur solution not working

Comment: Check your index.php in the ci root.  What environment is set?

Comment: Are you using codeigniter 2.1.*? If you use session database, it is the cause of this bug. Alternative way to fix this bug is disable the use of session database in config.php file. But then you have to  find a another solution for database session storage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that [error suppression](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) is not turned on for the function `imagecreatefromjpeg`

The best option is to extend the base library and overload the `image_create_gd` method

Create a new file `./application/libraries/MY_Image_lib.php`

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class MY_Image_lib extends CI_Image_Lib {

function image_create_gd($path = '', $image_type = '')
{
    if ($path == '')
        $path = $this->full_src_path;

    if ($image_type == '')
        $image_type = $this->image_type;


    switch ($image_type)
    {
        case     1 :
                    if ( ! function_exists('imagecreatefromgif'))
                    {
                        $this->set_error(array('imglib_unsupported_imagecreate', 'imglib_gif_not_supported'));
                        return FALSE;
                    }

                    return @imagecreatefromgif($path);
            break;
        case 2 :
                    if ( ! function_exists('imagecreatefromjpeg'))
                    {
                        $this->set_error(array('imglib_unsupported_imagecreate', 'imglib_jpg_not_supported'));
                        return FALSE;
                    }

                    return @imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
            break;
        case 3 :
                    if ( ! function_exists('imagecreatefrompng'))
                    {
                        $this->set_error(array('imglib_unsupported_imagecreate', 'imglib_png_not_supported'));
                        return FALSE;
                    }

                    return @imagecreatefrompng($path);
            break;

    }

    $this->set_error(array('imglib_unsupported_imagecreate'));
    return FALSE;
}

}
```

Comment: I definitely do not recommend adding the @ error suppression... check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php/36892995#36892995

Answer (score 4):

Try Adding @imagecreatefromjpeg($img) instead of imagecreatefromjpeg($img)

here @ is error suppressor

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exactly the same issue. I was first storing the image data on a local HDD before using the function **imagecreatefromjpeg()** to post-process the image further.

At certain times the locally stored image was corrupted during the store process and when called by **imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);** the PHP Warning:  ***imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file occured.*** showed up.

So to resolve the PHP warnings and to make up for the corrupted image I used a clearly defined solution in the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) see the function **LoadJpeg($imgname)**

To prevent the further failures I have focused on the reason why the data supplied to **imagecreatefromjpeg()** function was not integrious in the first place. In my case it was the network flood issue which was causing some images to arrive corrupted.

Long story short, you may want to check what exactly is being supplied into **imagecreatefromjpeg()** function before trying to extend the base library etc..

Answer (score 0):

I checked that my JPG file was corrupted when I got this error. Consider checking yours.