# imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file

Tags: php, yii, web

Not loaded Feed on the http://example.com/directory/directory/userPosts,

firefox issue:

imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file

add in index.php

ini_set(‘gd.jpeg_ignore_warning’, 1);

but not solved.

Comment: log:

{\rtf1\ansi\deff0\nouicompat{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{*\generator Riched20 6.4.9879}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang9 imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file (/home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/protected/modules_core/file/libs/ImageConverter.php:280) Stack trace: #0

Comment: Where is your code? Unclear what you are doing.

Comment: im try to upload large pictues exsample 7000px, and it not show on site, and got error like imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file

add in index.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735666/gd-jpeg-libjpeg-recoverable-error-premature-end-of-jpeg-file-in-codeigniter