# Meaning/purpose of the mysqli "at" symbol

Tags: php, mysqli

While reading the php documentation on the mysqli functions I came across some code that I wasn't sure what it meant:

```
$mysqli = @new mysqli('localhost', 'fake_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

What does the "@" mean and what is its purpose?

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php

Comment: Possible duplication of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php

Comment: you mean ignore warnings? reference would be `&`

Comment: @DaveChen if you are referring to the title of question I posted as duplicate, it's not about php reference mechanism, but 'question to refer to, when asked about "what does this symbol mean in php"'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@` suppresses errors in php.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: better to vote to close for the duplicate than have this answered for the billionth time

Answer (score 1):

The `@` operator suppresses error messages created by the following code. In this special case, a failure to connect will not result in a logged (or displayed) error, but will most likely be caught further on.