# What is the purpose of the "at" sign in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, documentation, phpdoc

I've been developing on WordPress for a couple of years now and I keep seeing the "at" (`@`) sign in themes and plugins comments.

What is it for? Does it serve a special purpose in WordPress? Or is it just a general programming documentation thing? I haven't been able to find anything about it thus far.

Examples of what I've seen in code:

```
@see woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs()
@uses load_theme_textdomain() For translation/localization support.
@since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
@return void
@param string $title Default title text for current view.
```

If there is documentation somewhere on what this is and how it should be used, I'd love to find it since this question has been bugging me for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are [tags for PHPDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc#Tags), the PHP equivalent of Javadoc. These comment blocks can later be parsed by a tool like [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) to generate useful documentation.

Comment: Thanks! This has been driving me crazy. Now that I know it's for documentation I'll be using these tags in all my future projects. Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

It silences error messages (which in plugins and themes prevents them from being displayed to users). See this StackOverflow thread for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032169/1293256

Comment: Not in this case, no. These are located in comment blocks.