# How to find error code/reason when stream_socket_accept() fails

Tags: php, sockets, error-handling

I have a stream socket server written in PHP. 
To see how many connections it can handle at a time,I wrote a simulator in C to create 1000 different clients to connect to the server.

`stream_socket_accept` was returning false a few times.
I need to find out the reason for this failure.

I tried `socket_last_error()` and `socket_strerror()` to get the error codes, but they returned 'Success'. These functions don't seem to be working on stream-sockets. Is there any way/ method to find out the actual error codes

My code:

```
$socket = @stream_socket_accept($this->master, "-1", $clientIp);

$ip = str_getcsv($clientIp, ":");

//socket accept error

if($socket === FALSE)

{

$this->logservice->log($this->module_name, "ERROR", "cannot accept the device connection");

  ***// Need to find error code here ***

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to see PHP level error messages in my logs now. `@` operator before `stream_socket_accept` was suppressing the error messages. ([@ symbol in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php) )