# PHP: Get fopen() HTTP response error code

Tags: php, http-headers, fopen

I would like to get the HTTP error code while opening a remote file via `fopen()` function.

I have the following code:

```
$remote = fopen ($url, "rb");
```

If the URL is fine, the file would be opened. Otherwise, `fopen` triggers an error message similar to `Warning: fopen(url): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`.

I know that adding a `@` before the `fopen()` would [suppress the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php),
but **how can I get the http error code** instead?

Here, I want to get `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` in a variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) will return the response header.
So you can get the first line by using `$http_response_header[0]` which in this case, will be exactly `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`.

```
$remote = @fopen ($url, "rb");
if (!$remote) {
   echo "Error: " . $http_response_header[0];
}
```