# In PHP, what does the 'at' symbol before an L-value mean?

Tags: php, semantics

Everything I can find refers to the use of the `@` symbol as a prefix to an *expression*, e.g.:

```
$foo = @bar();
```

This is *not* what I'm talking about here. I have a statement which uses the `@` symbol as a prefix to an L-value, like:

```
@$foo = bar();
```

What does this mean?

(Ideally, please explain the semantics as a de-sugaring of this statement into one that does not use the `@` symbol.)

Comment: Flagged as duplicate. This is covered in the PHP operators reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php and specifically here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@` symbol is used to [suppress error messages](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When
> prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be
> generated by that expression will be ignored.

For example;

The following code doesn't produce any errors on screen;

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

@$foo = $bar;

echo $foo;
```

However, without the `@` it does;

> Notice: Undefined variable: bar in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 6

Comment: On the **LHS** of an assignment?

Comment: @Quentin:- Yes I think so(Do correct me if I am wrong) I have read this:-`PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.`

Comment: @R.T. wait -- are you saying that the expression that it precedes is `$foo = bar()`? So the code parses as `@($foo = bar());`? That's certainly one explanation.

Comment: @jameshfisher:- Indeed!