# image display, php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a project `Personl` and I have encountered a problem.

## Details my of problem

Perform a query via a form, which calls me to another page where the query is displayed, everything is correct, it displays the information that I need, but when viewing the user's image, calling me by request the ID corresponding to this user, but not my image code is displayed below.

**Code to display the image in html:**

```
<img src="../../registro/imagen.php?matricula=<?php echo $_POST['matricula']; ?>" width="150px" height="150px" />
```

**Code search the image by id to display:**

```
 <?php
$numero=$_REQUEST['matricula'];
$tabla="alumno";
include("../../Connections/colegio.php");
$conexion=@mysqli_connect($hostname_colegio,$username_colegio,$password_colegio,$database_colegio);
    $sacar = "SELECT * FROM ".$tabla." WHERE (matricula=$numero)" ;
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sacar);
while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))echo mysqli_error( $conexion );{
            $tipo_foto=$registro['matricula'];
             header("Content-type: image/jpg");
             echo $registro['matricula'];
}



mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you suppressing errors?

Comment: Forgive but do not understand your question, you can guide me please

Comment: Remove @ symbol in your connection string

Comment: Thanks Subin Thomas, I have removed the @, but still, the image is not displayed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php Read this @user2766089

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($conexion))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: this line is causing you trouble `while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))echo mysqli_error( $conexion );{` for a few reasons.

Comment: hi thanks again, I removed the @ to display the error, which apparently have to capture, to know which is the call from the browser "../../registro/imagen.php?matricula=" in the browser only show me the broken image icon, any suggestions please?

Comment: simple, remove this `echo mysqli_error( $conexion );` from `while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))echo mysqli_error( $conexion );{`

Comment: thanks Fred, for you support, went back to search with ID 2015051439  in my database and the photo that corresponds to the same ID, this , the result of this search is "<img src =" ../../ registration / imagen.php? enrolls = 2015051439 "width =" 150px "height =" 150px ">" brings me, the id command to seek enrollment, but not I add the .jpg format, and the image is broken, if I type the full path 2015051439.jpg adding at the end, I get the same broken image.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` data directly into a query.

Comment: Thanks Tadman, you can suggest me change, excuse my ignorance but I am newbie in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may terminate this issue, if it helps someone, I leave the correct code.

```
    <?php  
$numero=$_REQUEST['matricula'];
  $consulta="select * from alumno WHERE (matricula = $numero)";
  $busca_fotos=mysql_query($consulta) or die("Error en: $busca_fotos:" .mysql_error()) ;
  while($ro=mysql_fetch_assoc($busca_fotos)){
   $url=$ro['matricula'];  

     echo  "
                <img src=\"../../registro/fotos/".$url.".jpg\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\" alt=\"\" />

            </a>
       ";
  }
?>
```