# What does the '@' sign in front of a function do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/app/components/View.js line 7 reads `@translate(['view', 'nav'])`

I don't understand what the @ does? otherwise it looks like it is just calling a function?

Comment: You can check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php

Comment: The question you linked is in regards to PHP code, is this true for Javascript as well?

Comment: it's an [ES2016 decorator](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.a9e11tbxb)

Comment: @MauricioPoppe: Decorators are not part of ES2016. It's a proposal for a future ES version. (the article is older)

Comment: @FelixKling you're right thanks :)

Comment: some stupid people just love to down vote

Comment: I'ld also like to point out that searching for this is really difficult, since there are @ signs everywhere on the net and I lacked any meaningful phrase (since I didn't know what it was supposed to be)