# PHP script still terminated even with @ operator

Tags: php

I am currently running a script that is failing to work, it turns out that there is this line:

```
$this->conn_id = @ftp_connect($this->ftp_server);
```

This line throw `ftp_connect` function undefined, but as it's preceded by `@` operator, shouldn't it not terminated?

Anyway I checked there is `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the beginning of the script. Is this the cause?

Thanks!

Comment: The suppressor-operator only prevents the error from being logged. If it's a fatal error, the script will still stop executing. You can wrap it with `function_exists()`, and only use it if it's defined.

Comment: `@` doesn't prevent errors, it will just suppress them so they aren't shown.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php

Comment: `@` doesn't prevent fatal errors, just like wrapping your head in a towel doesn't prevent you from getting hit in the head with a baseball bat. All it does is prevent you from seeing things.

Comment: are you getting the error because of wrong server url?

Comment: @RyanVincent So I bought the script from codecanyon.net, a certain function isn't working and I am not getting any error whatsoever, so it turns out that line is getting the script terminated without giving error, I thought `@` will suppress error and let the script going, how silly of me.

Comment: Thanks Qirel and Marc B, your answers clear things up for me.

Comment: when you say certain function? are you talking about a ufo? you should go through the entire script and make sure it's in a working order; maybe you didn't follow right documentation and system requirements.

Comment: @unixmiah unfortunately the documentation is minimal and isn't mentioning anything about requiring ftp module. Also the script author suppressed the error made me confused on what was wrong, I finally found out the error using `register_shutdown_function ` from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2146171/4561463.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like in php  doc  http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

> The @-operator works only on expressions. A simple rule of thumb is:
>   if you can take the value of something, you can prepend the @ operator
>   to it. For instance, you can prepend it to variables, function and
>   include calls, constants, and so forth. You cannot prepend it to
>   function or class definitions, or conditional structures such as if
>   and foreach, and so forth.

this mean that if the error is not related to the pure expression ..(like a fatal error) the error i raised ..

Answer (score 1):

As previous answers has specified @ doesnt work to suppress error when a function doesnt exits, however

```
if (function_exists('ftp_connect')){
        $this->conn_id = ftp_connect($this->ftp_server);
 }
```

will do the trick