# PHP what does @return do?

Tags: php

What does this even do?

```
/**
 * @return null|string
 */
```

I'm really confused. I'm applying the leskov substitution principle but does it do anything to a function? or just a note?

Comment: You want to read about `PHPDOC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a phpdoc-style documentation comment. It makes generating documentation for reference easier, and most IDEs will pick up on it.

See https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/getting-started/your-first-set-of-documentation.html

Comment: THANK YOU! Last question, So it's for an IDE then? like for example if I put a @return string the IDE will display a redline if the return type is not string?

Comment: IDEs may treat it differently, but it's a comment. It doesn't actually matter to the language, it just helps the humans writing it. So, I doubt it would cause any flags in your editor. Or, it would just be a notice.

Comment: In PHP 7, you can specify the return types of a function to the language itself using `method(): returntype {`, but the documentation comment does nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bytewave.

Answer (score 0):

It does nothing. `/*` and `*/` define a *comment block*.

Interestingly in PHP, the `@` symbol in actual code suppresses any errors that might be caused by that code: see [What is the use of the @ symbol in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php)

But, **most likely**, the whole thing could be simply some *documentation*, and the `@` used to indicate some documentation metadata.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that's just a comment as that is wrapped in "/**/" tag