# PHP - Is there a way to get a variable value if it is set?

Tags: php, function, isset, unset, notice

I always find myself writing something like:

```
if(isset($var))
{
    DoSomethingWith($var);
}
else
{
    DoSomethingWith(null);
}
```

or

```
if(isset($arr["key"]))
{
    DoSomethingWith($arr["key"];
}
else
{
    DoSomethingWith(null);
}
```

My question is exacly this:

Is there a way to write a *get_var_if_set()* function so that you can simply write...

```
DoSomethingWith(get_var_if_set($var));
/// and
DoSomethingWith(get_var_if_set($arr["key"]));
```

....WITHOUT notifying if *$var* doesn't exists or that *$arr* doesn't have a set value for "key"?

I guess it should be something like this:

```
function get_var_if_set($a)
{
    return (isset($a) ? $a : null);
}
```

But that doesn't work because calling *get_var_if_set()* with unset variables will always generate a **Notice**, so it might need a little magic.

Thanks all folks.

**Edit**
A user who deleted his answer suggested to pass variables by reference, as PHP will pass null if the $variable doesn't exist.

So that would be perfect, take a look at these **solutions** (which might probably be [equivalent](https://eval.in/789770)):

```
function get_var_if_set(&$a) { return (isset($a) ? $a : null); }
function get_var_if_set(&$a) { return $a ?? null; } // Only in PHP 7.0+ (Coalescing operator)
```

Note: Coalescing operator suggested by [Koray Küpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3004106/koray-k%C3%BCpe)

The problem [as you can see](https://eval.in/789770) is that they initialize the passed variables somehow in the return statement.
We don't want that.

Comment: In a new document, compare `echo $a;` vs `echo @$a;`. Although I think suppressing errors is generally not a good thing at all.

Comment: You can simply use: `DoSomethingWith($var??null);` or `DoSomethingWith($var?:null);`

Comment: @LucasKrupinski what is the use of `@` in front of a variable?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos - `@` [suppresses errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php)

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos it is used to suppress errors and warnings

Comment: @Thamilan That's very useful! Thank you

Comment: Simply use this `return($a)?$a:null;`

Comment: function get_var_if_set($a=null)
    {
        return $a;
    }   May be this is what you want to do here the function set the default value of argument to null so if you enter value it will be returned else the function return null , But is that useful

Comment: @LucasKrupinski in fact I didn't want to suppress by using that @!

Comment: @sunilwananje I also didn't want that extra operation! But thanks both for playing! =)

Comment: @KamranKhatti nope

Comment: @Osama nope as well

Answer (score 4):

If you use PHP 7.0+ you can use null coalescing operator.

```
return $a ?? null;
```

Note: The operator checkes whether the variable exist and not empty. So, if the variable is already set but empty, it will return the null variable already.

Comment: That's smart, but [it does spit out notifications](https://eval.in/789705)! The problem is when you execute 
_call_a_function_with($some_unexistent_parameter);_ PHP gets angry. I want a "magic function" that tells PHP "It doesn't matter what I'm passed, nor if it exists or not, I'm built to handle undefined indexesand unknown variables."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the var itself, but the key of the array `key` in this:

```
DoSomethingWith(get_var_if_set($arr["key"]))
```

So the only solution is to check for the array and the key you're looking for.

```
function get_var_if_set($a, $key = null)
{
    if(is_array($a) && array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        return $a[$key]; 
    } else {
          return (isset($a) ? $a : null);
    }
}
```

Comment: The coolness of the function isset() is that you can give it things that don't exist, and at most you will get false; PHP knows isset() might receive inexistent variables and it doesn't notify it. I want sort of wrapper-function for isset, that gives you directly [value or null], not [true or false]. Your solution ignores the problem that if you call get_var_if_set($inexistent_var), PHP tells you (with a notice) that $inexistent_var doesn't exist.