# Count unique values in one column of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, counting, array-column

I have this php array named `$ids`:

```
Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( [id] => 10101101 ) 
     [1] => Array ( [id] => 18581768 ) 
     [2] => Array ( [id] => 55533322 ) 
     [3] => Array ( [id] => 55533322 ) 
     [4] => Array ( [id] => 64621412 )
)
```

And I need to make a new array containing each `$ids` `id` value, as the new keys, and the times each one appears, as the new values.

Something like this:

```
$newArr = array(
    10101101 => 1,
    18581768 => 1,
    55533322 => 2,
    64621412 => 1,
);
```

This is what I have:

```
$newArr = array();
$aux1 = "";

//$arr is the original array
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
    $val = $arr[$i]["id"];
    if($val != $aux1){
        $newArr[$val] = count(array_keys($arr, $val));
        $aux1 = $val;
    }
}
```

I supose `array_keys` doesn't work here because $arr has the id values in the second dimension.

So, how can I make this work?

Sorry for my bad english and thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) will create an array of all the elements in a specific column of a 2-D array, and [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) will count the repetitions of each value in an array.

```
$newArr = array_count_values(array_column($ids, 'id'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Or do it by hand like this where `$arr` is your source array and `$sums` is your result array.

```
$sums = array();
foreach($arr as $vv){
    $v = $vv["id"];
    If(!array_key_exists($v,$sums){
        $sums[$v] = 0;
    }
    $sums[$v]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse your array, and sum the id appearance, [**live demo**](https://eval.in/818015).

```
$counts = [];
foreach($array as $v)
{
  @$counts[$v['id']] += 1;
}
print_r($counts);
```

Comment: Hi, what's the use of @?

Comment: Refer to this post [What is the use of the @ symbol in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1032161/6521116).