# unable to print table data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, datatable

need print column data in my laravel app. My controller is TaskController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $tasks = Task::all();
    return view('tasks.index')->with('tasks', $tasks);
    }
```

index.blade.php file is

```
@if(isset($tasks)) 
@foreach ($tasks as $task)
<h1>{{ $task->task_name }}</h1>
@endforeach
@endif
```

I am going include this index view file in show.blade.php file as following

```
@include('tasks.index')
```

but unable to print table data no any errors occurred. how can I print task_name in show view file?

Comment: `no errors occurred` really? Could it be because of all your @´s? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php

Comment: The `@` is part of Laravel's blade templating, it's not an error suppressor.

Comment: `@include('tasks.index')` includes just the blade file, not the data from the controller. Try passing the tasks in with the controller that returns the `show` blade.

Comment: do you have any solutions

Comment: Can you show the controller that returns the show view? I can show you how to tweak that.

Comment: you mean may I put a function to TaskControler to show tasks data? I do not have any show function in My TaskController

Comment: Which Controller function returns the `show.blade.php`? That's where you want to add the tasks in.

Comment: I called both ProjectController and TaskController functions show.blade.php in this case I need call TaskController is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show data on task.index then use this code.

```
 public function index()
 {
  $tasks = Task::all();
  //this line will pass $task data to this view     
  return view('tasks.index',compact('tasks'));
  }
```

Comment: use $task at task.index and doesn't need to include this file.
@include('tasks.index')

Answer (score 0):

If you are including the index blade inside the show blade, then you need to change your controller and pass data to the final blade (show instead of index) like this

```
return view('tasks.show')->with('tasks', $tasks);
```