# codeigniter modify array from string for insert_batch

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, explode

This is my form input `$data`, i want this keep this input.

```
$data = "39X3,29X5";
```

this my code convert string to array

```
$data = explode(",", $data);

$out = array();
$step = 0;

foreach($data as $key=>$item){
   foreach(explode('X',$item) as $value){
   $out[$key][$step++] = $value;
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($out);
print '</pre>';
```

**result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 39
        [1] => 3
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [2] => 29
        [3] => 5
    )
)
```

but i want change the keys and fix this for support query builder class

```
$this->db->insert_batch('mytable',$out).
```

Like this.

```
array
(
    array
    (
        'number' => 39
        'prize' => 3
    ),
    array
    (
        'number' => 29
        'prize' => 5
    )
)
```

i try hard and confuse using loop.

Comment: `foreach(explode(",", $data) as $item) {
    $out[] = array_combine(['number', 'prize'], explode('X',$item)); 
}`

Comment: thanks, this worth. i don't belive it's so simple

Answer (score 2):

So you need to remove inner `foreach` and put relevant values into array.

```
foreach($data as $key=>$item){
    $exp = explode('X', $item);
    $out[$key] = [
        'number' => $exp[0],
        'prize' => $exp[1]
    ];
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/1nWJY)

Comment: if i insert `$data = "39,29X5";` this will error `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /in/Y715I on line 9` but still viewed. how to remove this notice.

check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/Y715I)

Comment: @AGA Use [@ symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php) to hide notice https://3v4l.org/JqkRM

Answer (score 0):

change your `foreach` loop to the following:

```
foreach($data as $key=>$item){
  $temp = explode('X',$item);
  $out[] = ['number' => $temp[0] , 'prize' => $temp[1]];
}
```