# What is the difference between @$_FILES and $_FILES in php?

Tags: php

In some places for extracting data of a file `@$_FILES[]` is used. What is the difference between `@$_FILES[]` and `$_FILES[]`?

For example,

```
$pic = @$_FILES['uploadFile'];
```

and

```
$pic = $_FILES['uploadFile'];
```

Comment: `@` means no error will be reported https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of the @ symbol in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP `@` is an operator used to ignore error messages.

From [PHP.net](https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.