# ldap_bind fails with Warning but continues with if statment

Tags: php, ldap

I am authenticating with ldap and have it all working when the correct credentials are put in however if the user is not valid or the password is incorrect the ldap_bind gives the following warning:

```
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials...
```

This means the following line which i think should check if the ldap_bind has worked is being executed when it should fail:

```
$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn,"uid=$username,cn=users,dc=abc,dc=net", "$password");
if ($ldapbind) {
```

Do i need to change the if statment so the warning for invalid credentials results in a fail and it moves onto the else statment ? I have tried the following but it hasn't made a difference.

```
if (($ds) !== false )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
$ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn,"uid=$username,cn=users,dc=abc,dc=net", "$password");
if ($ldapbind) {
```

Comment: Amazing that seems to have worked for me. Can you explain what the @ symbol does? or rather an explanation to why it works?

Comment: @a.smith https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php

Comment: The '@' suppresses error-messages. But in your case the error is a valid message and should not be suppressed. If the error-message is showing up in your output, that is a completely different topic. That would mean that you have `display_errors` set to `true` which you should **never, ever** do on a production system. For more info on the `@` have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php