# Laravel keeps giving me: "Undefined offset 2"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I try foreach loop but it keeps giving me "Undefined offset 2".

I tried also isset then I got "Undefined offset 1"

My code:

```
foreach ($lineArrayResults as $lineArrayResultKey => $lineArrayResult)
{
    $currentFormFieldId = $submittedFormFields[$lineArrayResultKey]; // this line gives me error.
    if($currentFormFieldId > 0)
    {
        $newLeadDataArray[$currentFormFieldId] = [
            'field_name' => $formFields[$currentFormFieldId],
            'field_value' => $lineArrayResult
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: undefined offset means that an array have ran out of bounds. the array size is smaller than the index that you are trying to fetch an object from.

Answer (score 1):

the error **undefined offset** means that an array have ran out of bounds. the array size is smaller than the index that you are trying to fetch an object from.

First of all make sure your `$submittedFormFields` array contains the key of `$lineArrayResultKey` variable, if the array key is dynamically generated then try this code

```php
foreach ($lineArrayResults as $lineArrayResultKey => $lineArrayResult)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($lineArrayResultKey, $submittedFormFields)){
        continue;
    }

    $currentFormFieldId = $submittedFormFields[$lineArrayResultKey];
    if($currentFormFieldId > 0)
    {
        $newLeadDataArray[$currentFormFieldId] = [
            'field_name' => $formFields[$currentFormFieldId],
            'field_value' => $lineArrayResult
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add @ before $
try this

```
foreach ($lineArrayResults as $lineArrayResultKey => $lineArrayResult)
{
    $currentFormFieldId = @$submittedFormFields[$lineArrayResultKey]; // insert @ before $
    if($currentFormFieldId > 0)
    {
        $newLeadDataArray[$currentFormFieldId] = [
            'field_name' => $formFields[$currentFormFieldId],
            'field_value' => $lineArrayResult
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Terrible solution. Operator @ is only for testing purposes and exceptions, not using in production.

Comment: Because it masks the problem, not solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php