# What is purpose of using @ sign with Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

What is purpose of @ sign with model in controller

```
 if($request->has('update'))
        {
            $userData = User::findOrFail($request->userID);
            $isvalid = @$userData->isvalid == '1' ? 'checked' : '';
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of the @ symbol in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php)

Comment: yes its was useful  answer for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a PHP operator helps to ignore warnings and errors