# How do I bind with multiple Active Directory OU with LDAP

Tags: php, ldap

I am creating a login page that uses Active Directory credentials. I found some documentation  about LDAP in the PHP Manual and managed to successfully login using Active Directory credentials by binding with LDAP.

My challenge is that I have multiple Organizational Units (OU) and can't find an efficient way to bind using OUs.

Currently I am using a for loop to loop over each OU in an array. However, this throws an error each time the incorrect OU is being used. I am new to LDAP and found resources that mentioned ldap_search; however, I was not able to successfully bind without including the OU. Any advice/ help would be great.

```
$ou=array("Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4", "Group5");



$arrlength = count($ou);

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++){



    
    
    
    $ldapuser = "CN=".$_POST["username"].",OU=".$ou[$x].",DC=com,DC=com";

    $ldappass = trim($_POST["password"]);
    

    //LDAP server connection

    
    $ldapserver = "ldaps:server.domain";

            
    

    //options are require, never, allow
    //require is most secure, the others could allow for man in the middle attacks
    putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=require');

        
    // connect to ldap server
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver) or die ("Couldn't connect");

    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = false;

   

      $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass);
      if ($ldapbind) {

     
          $x = $arrlength;

     }
```

Comment: Update: I found out that the @ sign in PHP can be used to suppress the PHP warning errors (source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-the-symbol-in-php). I merged the $ldapbind connection along with the if statement eg (if(@$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass)){  $x = $arrlength;}. This stopped the PHP Error warning which was really what I wanted. However, I am still want to know if there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common generic method (i.e. one that'll work with any kind of LDAP system) is:

1. Bind using a preconfigured "service" account and password. (Ask the AD admins to create a dedicated account for your webapp. They *might* need to add it to the "Pre-Win2000 systems" group.)
2. *Search* the LDAP directory for the username to find the correct user account object.

   (You can search by any attribute you like, but note that the username is usually `sAMAccountName`, *not* the CN – the CN field is supposed to hold the user's "real" name. This also means that a user's DN may change, so you have to search it every time.)
3. Unbind (disconnect), then connect/bind again with the user's DN that you just found.

If this is *specifically* Active Directory, there's a shortcut – you can bind to AD LDAP without knowing the user's DN at all, just by specifying the UPN (i.e. `username@domain`) within the "bind DN" field. This won't work with other server types, and won't be all that useful if you also need to retrieve the user's attributes (still need a search for that...)

Also, if this is AD, you'll usually want to disable the `REFERRALS` option.

Comment: Thank You! I initially had a service account for the application but I was thinking it would be more secure to bind with the user's credentials. However, I have successfully binded by using the username@domain which is much more efficient than what I was doing initially.